# Copy UITabBarController logic with default buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I want to have three VC's (A, B, C look at picture). And I want each VC to have three same buttons. And when user will press left button it will show A VC, when center button will be pressed - "B" VC will be shown and the same with the last one. Also I don't need view controllers to be created each button press, they have to save their state.

The same functionality has UITabBarController but I dont know how to implement it with buttons.

Can some one help me with my issue or show the right way to accomplish this?

[image: picture]

Comment: Just create 3 different views then show view related with button and hide other views

Comment: Do you want to do this in code or storyboard?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni What if one of the views has to be capturedCameraOutput? Will it work as needed without some glitching? And on the other view's I need to have navigation and status bars?

Comment: @HaydenHolligan I will choose any variant. It just need to work

Comment: Yes it should work try it.@mikle94

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Is there a way to separate vc's? I've got camera view and two tableView's in one VC and it will be very huge. I've also tried to create main view controller which contains view with buttons and a container view below them. This container view embeds a navigation controller in which i put created view controller's by storyboard id using `setViewControllers([settingsViewController], animated: false)` function. And it seems to work but i can't hide status bar and navigation bar from camera vc and show them on the two others. Any ideas?

Comment: How about using three full screen container views on the main VC. You can put buttons on the main VC to select which VC to move to front.  Then you can put each embedded VC in a NavCon if desired.

Comment: @vacawama Great idea, i'll try it now and tell if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach:

1. In your main view, add three overlapping container views.
2. Add buttons to the main view to switch between views (by bringing them to the front).
3. Configure the viewControllers however you want.  Embed them in a `NavigationController` if desired.
4. Add `@IBOutlets` to the container views.
5. In the `@IBAction` for each button, bring the corresponding view to front`

[image: simulated tab view]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerA: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var containerB: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var containerC: UIView!

    @IBAction func pressA(sender: UIButton) {
        view.bringSubviewToFront(containerA)
    }

    @IBAction func pressB(sender: UIButton) {
        view.bringSubviewToFront(containerB)
    }

    @IBAction func pressC(sender: UIButton) {
        view.bringSubviewToFront(containerC)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it as follows:

1. Add three buttons on the bottom of the Parent Controller.
2. Add three Container View's and make their respective separate classes so that your code is modular. Make sure height and width of all the containers are the same and it covers the full view leaving your buttons on the bottom. (Container Views are very easy to manage using storyboards)
3. Now make three outlets for all the three container views and make three actions for all the respective three buttons.
4. On button press hide the two container views you dont want to show and unhide the one you want to see.

With this you can get Tab Bar Controller like functionality.

PS: You should not use these kind of approach and one should use tab bar controllers where required.

Comment: About your comment, what if i got design from my customer where these three buttons looks not like default UITabBar? What else should i do?

Comment: You are an iOS expert hired by your customer, so you should tell your client recommended approaches and good architecture of an application. What you are trying to achieve is a work around, but not good iOS architecture. You should tell your client the apple recommended way and show him examples of apps developed by apple using tab bars.